# python: generating methods for a convenience class programatically

Tags: python, metaprogramming

So I've written a module that contains a bunch of functions to easily interact with a subprocess. This subprocess has a whole bunch of settings that let you change how it formats and behaves. I realized that it'd be nice to have a convenience class that you could use as a handler to store the settings you prefer to use and pass them on to the module level functions. here's the example code I'm doing testing with:

```
import inspect

class MyHandler(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.format_string='class format string'
        self.database='class database'
        self.mode = "class mode"

    def rename(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._pass_to_function(rename, *args, **kwargs)

    def _pass_to_function(self, function, *overrided_args, **overrided_kwargs):
        #  get the function's remaining arguments with the inspect module
        functon_kwargs = inspect.getargspec(function)[0][len(overrided_args):]

        handler_vars = vars(self)
        kwargs_to_pass = {}
        for arg in functon_kwargs:
            if arg in handler_vars:
                kwargs_to_pass[arg] = handler_vars[arg]
        for arg in overrided_kwargs:
            kwargs_to_pass[arg] = overrided_kwargs[arg]

        return function(*overrided_args, **kwargs_to_pass)


def rename(targets, format_string=None, database=None, mode=None,
           not_in_class='None'):
    print 'targets = {}'.format(targets)
    print 'format_string = {}'.format(format_string)
    print 'database = {}'.format(database)
    print 'mode = {}'.format(mode)
    print 'not_in_class = {}\n'.format(not_in_class)
    return
```

The thing I like about this solution is that it uses the attributes stored in the class, but you can easily override them by simply adding them to the method call if you want a one-off with a different setting. To do this I have the `_pass_to_function` as a kind of wrapper function to parse and fill in the needed settings and overrides. Here's how it looks:

```
>>> import argstest
>>> argstest.rename('some_file.avi', database='some database')
targets = some_file.avi
format_string = None
database = some database
mode = None
not_in_class = None

>>> tst = argstest.MyHandler()
>>> tst.rename('some_file.avi')
targets = some_file.avi
format_string = class format string
database = class database
mode = class mode
not_in_class = None

>>> tst.rename('some_file.avi', 'one off format string', not_in_class=True)
targets = some_file.avi
format_string = one off format string
database = class database
mode = class mode
not_in_class = True
```

Now in my real module I have dozens of module-level functions that I want to access from the handler class. Ideally they would generate automatically based on the functions in the module. Seeing as how all the methods are only going to be passing everything to `_pass_to_function` I get the sense that this shouldn't be very difficult but I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out exactly how.

I've read about using `type` to generate a meta-class, but I don't see how I would use it in this situation. Am I not seeing how I could use `type`? Should I use some sort of module level script that adds the functions with `setattr`? Is what I was doing the better/clearer way to do things?

Any and all advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to generate member functions for MyHandler based on the other functions found in the module. That's what the code above does, but it does it somewhat inelegantly.

Comment: Ok. I'm still trying to understand *why* you are wanting to do that. Are you trying to create the same function that is accessible in both a class and a convenience module-level function? Have a look at Python's logger module for an example of that.

Comment: If you look at the rename function, you can see it takes 4 arguments. in the module I'm writing there are functions that take up to 17. A single user will generally only need 1 or 2. But others will have several sets of many arguments that they use over and over again on different calls to the same function. Having a class that will hold these arguments and use them where appropriate would be convenient so you only have to set them once. I'd like to generate them automatically so that a change to the module level function is reflected in the class, without having to keep track of everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I've answered my own question for now. This is how the module looks:

```
import inspect
import sys
from types import MethodType


class MyHandler(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.format_string = 'class format string'
        self.database = 'class database'
        self.mode = "class mode"
        self._populate_methods()

    def _populate_methods(self):
        to_add = inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__], inspect.isfunction)
        to_add = [x[0] for x in to_add if not x[0].startswith('_')]
        for func_name in to_add:
            func = getattr(sys.modules[__name__], func_name)  # strings to functions
            self._add_function_as_method(func_name, func)

    def _add_function_as_method(self, func_name, func):
        def f(self, *args, **kwargs):  #  the template for the method we'll add
            return self._pass_to_function(func, *args, **kwargs)
        setattr(MyHandler, func_name, MethodType(f, None, MyHandler))

    def _pass_to_function(self, function, *overrided_args, **overrided_kwargs):
        functon_kwargs = inspect.getargspec(function)[0][len(overrided_args):]
        handler_vars = vars(self)
        kwargs_to_pass = {}

        for arg in functon_kwargs:
            if arg in handler_vars:
                kwargs_to_pass[arg] = handler_vars[arg]
        for arg in overrided_kwargs:
            kwargs_to_pass[arg] = overrided_kwargs[arg]

        return function(*overrided_args, **kwargs_to_pass)


def rename(targets, format_string=None, database=None, mode=None,
           not_in_class='None'):
    print 'targets = {}'.format(targets)
    print 'format_string = {}'.format(format_string)
    print 'database = {}'.format(database)
    print 'mode = {}'.format(mode)
    print 'not_in_class = {}\n'.format(not_in_class)
    return


def something_else():
    print "this function should become a method"


def _not_a_member():
    print "this function should not become a method"
```

I've added the `_populate_methods` and the `_add_function_as_method` member functions. the `_populate_methods` function gets the name of all "public" functions in the module, de-references them to their function and passes each one though `_add_function_as_method`. All this method does is use an internal function to capture arguments and sent them to `_pass_to_function`, and set that function as a method using setattr.

*phew*

so it works, but I'm still wondering if there isn't a clearer or more straight forward way to get this done. I'd be very grateful if anyone could chime in.